# Перенос базы данных из PHPMyAdmin в MariaDB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Всем доброго дня!

Ребята, не выходит экспортировать и далее импортировать базу данных. Распишу действия в Линукс:

1. Запуск PHPMyAdmin
2. Экспорт базы данных с одной таблицей из PHPMyAdmin в файл myDB.sql
3. Закрытие PHPMyAdmin
4. Перенос myDB.sql файла в папку, где хранятся базы данных MariaDB (/var/lib/mysql)
5. Запуск MariaDB в терминале
6. Запуск базы данных путем команды USE myDB

   СРАБОТАЛО, ОТВЕТ database changed
7. Далее вывод таблицы myTable путем команды SELECT *FROM myTable

   ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'myDB.myTable' doesn't exist

Почему он не видит таблицу в этой БД, если она там есть?

Comment: Потому что таблица не импортирована. Скопировать файл дампа - мало, его ещё нужно и развернуть, т.е. запустить на исполнение. И не факт, что он развернётся без ошибок, скорее будет наоборот... А то, что база назначения УЖЕ существует - совсем плохо. Если там лежат другие данные, то я даже и не знаю, что лучше - разворачивать дамп в другую БД, или переименовывать существующую... в любом варианте можно поиметь проблем.

Comment: Ничего не понял :-) Я изучаю SQL всего неделю. Для меня база данных - это файл, внутри которого есть таблицы. И если из PhpMyAdmin удачно экспортировался файл БД, то следовательно там обязана быть таблица. Она же была в этой БД, когда я работал с ней из PhpMyAdmin. Куда она делась после экспорта?

Comment: *если из PhpMyAdmin удачно экспортировался файл БД, то следовательно там обязана быть таблица.* Она там есть. Но не в том виде, в каком к ней можно получить доступ через сервер БД. Через блокнот - пожалуйста... ведь созданный файл с дампом - это простой текст. Чтобы работать с таблицей как с таблицей БД, надо скормить этот файл серверу БД, чтобы он конвертировал данные обратно в свой формат. Через тот же PhpMyAdmin, например - там, где есть пункт "Экспорт", непременно найдётся и пункт "Импорт".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предварительно необходимо правильно произвести экспорт файла базы данных из PhpMyAdmin в каталог /var/lib/mysql с названием и расширением oldDB.sql

Основная работа в терминале:

1. Получаем привелегия root пользователя

   sudo -i
2. Переходим в папку с файлом БД

   cd /var/lib/mysql
3. Запускаем СУБД MariaDB

   systemctl start mariadb
4. Запускаем MySql

   mysql -u root -p
5. Создаем пустую базу данных

   CREATE DATABASE MyDB;
6. Выходим из MariaDB

   Ctrl+D
7. Производим сам импорт базы данных в MariaDB

   mysql -u root -p myDB < oldDB.sql

Проверка успешности:

8. mysql -u root -p
9. USE MyDB
10. SHOW TABLES - тут должны показаться все таблицы

В указанном порядке у меня все получилось. Исползованный [ресурс](https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/kak-importirovat-i-eksportirovat-bazy-dannyh-v-mysql-i-mariadb-1)